# serving webapps out of arbitrary subfolders with nginx

Tags: nginx, directory

I'm serving webapps out of arbitrary subfolders on a domain. i.e.

```
example.com/app-one (with example.com/app-one/page served by app-one)
example.com/folder/app-two (with example.com/folder/app-two/page served by app-two)
```

I have a nginx config that works just fine for the root level, but I'm a little stumped on how to handle subfolders. I could make `location /app-one` blocks, of course, but we have dozens of these and we'd like to avoid having to expliticly specify each one.

Is there any way to get `try_files` to essentially recurse up the folder structure until it hits an index.php file?

```
server {
    server_name example.com

    location / {
        root /srv/web/example.com;
        index index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$q&$args;
    }

    # pass *.php files to the PHP tier
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /srv/web/example.com;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first location statement should care for those requests inside subfolders.

I'm wondering what's on nginx's logfiles.

Comment: No, they don't. A request to /app-one/page means nginx looks for `/app-one/page`, `/app-one/page/`, then `/index.php`. I need it going to `/app-one/index.php` in that situation. Logs don't show anything interesting, even if I custom log out the various FastCGI vars.

Comment: Maybe your config is never ending up reaching the fastCGI location, try putting your fastCGI params inside `location /` directive and get rid of the `location ~ \.php$` directive altogheter.

Comment: It definitely hits the FastCGI stuff, as the root-level index.php correctly executes. I need to know how to recursively fallback in `try_files` rather than just going straight to /index.php. Tried stuff like `try_files $uri $uri/ ../../index.php ../index.php /index.php` without success.

Comment: please try to change `root index.php index.html` directive outside of `location /` and just place it inside `server` definition.